# Serve nodejs app on traefik and docker swarm

Tags: node.js, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a docker swarm environment with traefik and applications that are running on a domain. One application is e.g. on domain [www.test.de/app1](http://www.test.de/app1) another is e.g. on [www.test.de/app2](http://www.test.de/app2). The applications are served by docker instances that run apache. Here on the one hand I create a service label with the label `traefik.frontend.rule` and the value `Host: www.test.de;PathPrefix: /app1`. Furthermore the dockerfile in the Image cares for apache to serve to the right path like

```
RUN   echo 'Alias app1 "/var/www/html"' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN   echo 'Alias app1/ "/var/www/html/"' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Now, I have a simple node application (locally it is working fine) that should work with traefik on [www.test.de/app3](http://www.test.de/app3) using traefik.

I have a simple dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I also have a simple server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const webpush = require('web-push');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const low = require('lowdb');
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync');
const adapter = new FileSync('db.json');
const db = low(adapter);

const http = require('http');
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cors());


const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

httpServer.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('HTTP Server running on port 80');
})
```

The packages are already installed in the folder `/usr/src/app` through a mount of a volume. I created the service with the frontend rule label `traefik.frontend.rule` and the value `Host: www.test.de;PathPrefix: /app3`. When I start a container, it is saying in the console

> console.log('HTTP Server running on port 80');

so I can see that the service is running. But I cannot access the frontend (simple index.html). I think, that I have to adjust some settings in node like in apache explained above. But which ones?

Comment: You have not copied any files into the image, merely declared the WORKDIR as /usr/src/app.

Comment: Made an edit. I mounted the data to /usr/src/app where all the packages are.